# sharepoint online backup site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I got new issue from my client. He want to back up sharepoint site for restore, if something is going wrong. And the challenge is not to use 3rd party solution(MetaVis, AveDoc). Is there any other way to get back up? I think about to write my own application for backing up,maybe using CSOM, but i don't find a way to connect SharePoint storage(site description schema), where could I start? Please, share your experience if you had challenges like that.I want to find programmatic solution for this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/akieft/archive/2012/01/09/restore-options-in-sharepoint-online.aspx) link, we can see there are only 4 ways to restore data in SharePoint Online:

1. Site Collection Restore

   - Backups are taken every 12 hours, and are kept for 14 days.
   - You must contact technical support to perform a site collection restore.
   - The data will be restored to the same url that it was taken from.  You cannot restore to a different url, and you will lose any current data.
2. Recycle Bin

   - This is pretty self-explanatory.  Details can be found [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-online-small-business-help/manage-the-recycle-bin-of-a-sharepoint-site-HA101969189.aspx) and [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/view-restore-or-delete-items-in-the-recycle-bin-of-a-site-HA101967280.aspx).
3. Versioning

   - Again, this one is also pretty self-explanatory.  Details can be found [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-library-HA101853103.aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262378.aspx).
4. 3rd Party Solutions

   - The more diverse and robust option of the four, the only downside is having to pay.
   - Usually allow you to backup/restore items at a more granular level.
   - Some options:

     1. [Avepoint](http://www.avepoint.com/sharepoint-online-migration-docave/)
     2. [Quest](http://www.quest.com/migrator-for-sharepoint-online/)
     3. [Metalogics](http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Migration-Manager-for-SharePoint.aspx)
     4. [Metavis](http://www.metavistech.com/solutions)
     5. [Thinkscape](http://www.thinkscape.com/)

Comment: I know this four ways. But as I say I have no chance to use 3rd party solution like MetaVis and etc. So i think if this 3rd party solutions have some access to data, they maybe use the same csom. So there must be some way to access and backup data.